# HP laptop G71-329wm no boot

Tags: boot, laptop

At boot up, **Power, Wireless and Bat chg** lights turn on for 3 secs then unit shuts down. No onscreen video what so ever!

I changed RAM modules(*2 qty*) out and now unit partially boots, **Power, Wireless and Bat chg** are lit, and stays powered up to the point where the caps lock lights (*two of them*) blink three times then pauses, blinks 3 times and pauses and so on, but still no onscreen video what so ever!

HP Blink code says defective memory first, (*installed new pair RAM modules 2x 2gb DDR3*) and if that don't solve problem (*it didn't*) defective motherboard!

Installed new motherboard, with new DDR3 RAM modules and same condition exists, powers up, **Power,Wireless and Bat chg** are lit, caps lock lights blink(*3 x sequence*), and nothing further. No video display what so ever,  **NO PRODUCT NAME/MODEL, NO BIOS/POST screen nothing**.

Anyone else seen/had this problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

HP G71-329wm needs DDR2, not DDR3: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/HP-Compaq/hp-g71-329wm

Comment: Michaelbay, thanks for reply, that was a typing error. It is in fact DDR2. I'm getting answers that the video chip needs to be "reballed" ! Do you know what that is? I am not familiar with a procedure called "reballed"!

Comment: Reballing is resoldiering a chip. Probably not worth it but you can take it to a professional.